# List Operation in the most efficient way possible

Tags: algorithm

I need to perform a couple of operations on contents of a list. The List holds the weight of the edges and the other in which these edges appear in my graph.

What I would like to do is without reshuffling my List, ensure that for each x value in my list, the total sum of the remaining values in the list is greater than x. If this is not the case,  then x needs to be deleted from the list.

eg assume my list contains the digits 3 4 5 23 3 31 10 100 3 5

since (3+4+5+23+3+31+10+5) is less than 100, 100 will need to be deleted from the list.

So far, what I have been able to come up with is

```
static double calculatesum(List<Edge> e)
        {
            double total = e.Sum(item => item.segmentlength);
            //what I want to check each and then delete when I hit one I need to deactivate
            foreach (Edge edge in e)
            {
                if (1 > (total - edge.segmentlength))
                {
                    edge.isactive = false;
                    total -= edge.segmentlength;
                }
            }

            return 0;
        }
```

How do I accomplish this in the more efficient way?

Comment: Is this homework?  If so, it should be tagged as such.

Comment: OK, I'm assuming that now. Good luck!

Comment: It seems like this would destroy all lists, since the very last element would be removed (because there isn't anything after it), then the element before that one (because it's now the end of the list), then the element before that one, etc.  Can you clarify?

Comment: The last element will not be removed given that the total sum of the remaining elements in the list is greater than the value of the last element. I edited my entry to make it clearer.

Comment: If you are not allowed to reshuffle you would be O(n^2), if you're allowed to reshuffle or at least create a new reshuffled list you can get O(n+n log n) complexity. What's it gonna be? BTw is this homework?

Comment: Oh wait, I'm wrong sorry. Without reshuffling you get away with O(n), sorry for the confusion.

Comment: This is not homework. This is my work. I guess I can reshuffle but I would eventually need to sort it back to the previous order later on the code. This is why I don't want to do a reshuffle. What I did instead was, for each node in list, I kept position variable to hold this information.

Comment: How can it be O(n) if I am having to calculate the sum, and then do a compare for each element?

Comment: you are right I forgot the multiple run problem after removing an element

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what you mean by most effective.

If you're looking for best asymptotic complexity, then do a sort (and remember the place of each element). Since you have simple numbers in the list, perhaps with limited weights you might be able to do better than `O(n*log n)`. Then simply calculate a sum, then repeatedly substract the last element, compare it with the sum, and remove it if necessary till you finished.

If usually there are only a couple of elements you have to remove, then simply search for the maximum element in the sum and repeat this procedure until there are no elements to remove.

Answer (score 0):

To make it O(n) do the following:

```
1. create sum of all elements 
2. for each element
2a. substract element from sum
2b. check new sum against element
2ba if to remove remember element
2bb else add element to sum
3. remove remembered elements
```

until here it would be O(n)

I forgot to consider multiple runs of this until no element is removed anymore. So worst case being O(n^2)  for unshuffled and O(n+ n log n) in case of presort.